# firebase analytics error when preforming segue

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

The app crashes when I perform the segue. I checked if there was any sigbrt errors, but there was not. I think it is firebase analytics from the log. This error was from the log :

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

The code

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField! 
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var adduser: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var errormessege: UILabel!

var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    password.isSecureTextEntry = true
    adduser.isEnabled = false

}

@IBAction func didtapcancel(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}






@IBAction func didtapadd(_ sender: Any) {
    adduser.isEnabled = false

   FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: {(user,error) in

        if error != nil {

            if error!._code == 17999 {
                       self.errormessege.text =  "Invalid email address"   }
            else {

              self.errormessege.text =  error?.localizedDescription
            }
        }

        else
        {


           FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.email.text!, password: self.password.text!, completion: {(user,error) in

                if (error == nil) {


                    self.databaseref.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("email").setValue(self.email.text!)

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "hi", sender: nil)



                }
                else {
                    self.errormessege.text =  error?.localizedDescription

                }
            })
        }


    }
    )


     }



@IBAction func didtextchange(_ sender: Any) {

        if((email.text?.characters.count)!>0){
        adduser.isEnabled = true}
    else{
        adduser.isEnabled = false}

}
    @IBAction func did4(_ sender: Any) {
    if((password.text?.characters.count)!>0){
        adduser.isEnabled = true}
    else{
        adduser.isEnabled = false}
}
```

Comment: Can you enable Debug mode in Firebase Analytics (add -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled to your app Under Edit Scheme), and provide some of the debug log before the app crashes? Your information is limited so it's hard to tell whether it's Firebase Analytics or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code and the entire scenario in front of me it is hard to specifically nail down what is happening between your code and Firebase.  One thing that will significantly help you though in tracking down this error is to validate the data you are pulling out of your `@IBOutlets` each steps of the way.  That way your program is not force unwrapping these objects and leaving opening up your code to risk.

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField! 
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var adduser: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var errormessege: UILabel!

var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    password.isSecureTextEntry = true
    adduser.isEnabled = false
}

@IBAction func didtapcancel(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func didtapadd(_ sender: Any) {
    adduser.isEnabled = false

    guard let emailText = email.text,
       let passwordText = password.text else {
       // Handle error safely
       print("Error unrapping email text or password text")
       return
    }

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailText, password: passwordText, completion: { (user,error) in

        if error != nil {
            if error!._code == 17999 {
              self.errormessege.text =  "Invalid email address"   
            } else {
              self.errormessege.text =  error?.localizedDescription
            }
        } else {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailText, password: passwordText, completion: { (user, error) in

                if (error == nil) {
                    guard let uid = user.uid else {
                        // handle error safely
                        print("Error with user uid")
                        return
                    }
     self.databaseref.child("users").child(uid).child("email").setValue(emailText)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "hi", sender: nil)
                }
                else {
                    self.errormessege.text =  error?.localizedDescription

                }
            })
        }
    })
}

@IBAction func didtextchange(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let emailText = email.text else {
        // Return error safely
        print("Error unrapping email text")
        return
    }

    if emailText.characters.count> 0 {
        adduser.isEnabled = true
    } else{
        adduser.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```